# Initialising an array of objects using new

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor, new-operator

I have an 2 classes, `Acquisition` and `Scan`, which is defined as follows:

```
public class Scan
{
    public List<List<float>> myScan;
    public Scan()
    {
        myScan = new List<List<float>>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Acquisition()
{
    Scan[] scan;
    public Acquisition()
    {
        scan = new Scan[2];
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to make an array of `Scan` objects using the `new` method inside `Acquisition` class. However, when i run my debugger, I realized that the `scan` object returns `null` for `scan[1]` and `scan[2]`; it seems that the `Scan` constructor is not called.

I would like to know if there are any problems with this way of initializing.

Thanks!

Comment: you have initialized the array, now you need to populate the array, `scan[0] = new Scan();`

Comment: To paraphrase @kennyzx. You have created a box which can hold two `Scan`s (initialized the array). You now need to fill the box up (populate the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting it in an answer because it's in the comments: you need to populate the array. So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scan.length; i++)
{
    scan[i] = new Scan();
}
```

That seems to be the easiest way to make all of them Scan objects.